# Vertical Violin Plot in Vega

Tags: vega

I'm trying to swap the axes on the violin plot example provided by the Vega documentation [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/violin-plot). When attempting this myself ([link here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAExdgBsa47Tn1tM2uAA8kCU3G0QYbAO5Gy22TQiZlTBmoSENoAZmyKJnDitAzGTGyyAJ7ayBAQlNIgbrL0aAAcAAwFMvA0ZFhoAGxFMjhIsl7RaAIyUBIhZWigSFbeAEJI4rJdIEyDsgAKbBB06mgAjDJqUADWAKJWviiovgxwSzSrAPIhIRBwmGgFAL7XMjNk4kj6EGgA2qBPCHBoIKbmAHUaDkYJkGDhZEhMD90AAKbL0bQAWm0AGYCgBKAiokB3T62GEYOBlCoycGQ6G-UrlCwAKm081xUnx31+vhoCEyxGeezQu32oyMw1QoCMOACv1gcFW8SsuLxIC+hLGQwRoJk3P0vNQxUFQxGYol6EUgzIPxkCCMVwtPTQACYaiAfHAcAtbgBdGQU7YfRUE344KJkBhGV5kxT6X7egiB6Ih8TpUQSTJbBNhRSc1C+zCJQO-Dr6aGKTLWHDF9AUhgISgAZUDUBoCm0AEIALzacQMfT6bQAMl7nihVbeAHI+glkgBZJBpbSwsgYkfulvtzvd3HuhVKqNRGY5zJiBiKKCE2PB0Mpk1p8KZ7O5wkreSZDpwfTCkDjpLaaez+cYzJkIobDgkwiTvCAdbSo2ryeqM4xqiMDxPJG6AqrICF3CA1jQuIlwik6ZTIWyygINoAD8HZdj2qDaG8Do1NolQCEU7rypuzJ+qy6A+FCYZOsBx6nkG8Z8amEDpreoA5nm6BIGQgF8JSMiAcBOCgeBkENgoICwS+b6vFmH4Tt+M7BH+mSflOplzguFnGT+Zm2bBbB4OBACOjIWnAXiDJkbk4rBM7uZ5IDfD5kgyP5OnXJusHQM82lZiyhL6EgiTAZcSz3r8aGZFeZq-AhXpsMgVr4d6AbCReMh6e+mnQfKHHbugiTxfo5ogNJKVGHASDFjI+WEtSpIgEBsTCvyxWlRooAVegZ4ic+jZvr8lkmb+tmYbIJVIEYk5lbqABecBAWgITPOcMjiIcML8lu-roDAbUdV1vyGOIvX9aNpowm8xSgEhzwBmYmBAiCG5TbtM1yFC2xyLudBgTVy3vvICaI41yWSmwZhfa96DhI0QOQ2Vs2w5VcbVSAtW-PV2mYYNkpQuQ4RgTFMg9IlvrhI2uE5eYmAlQeUAJW9aUZZkh1CtYbocTzUR4SA7UhJlToi+1vyterHVS0MMuoPM7OhX1KwGXeMkgCp4LPkBmagOdJ54WTmBw2je5I5xhJ6DjVrKWNalgegdOvLcMhRG0T74QrJ0jFYUCIdrYvpRKyOvnV9YNTIuU6pQAiYQh+GAyhfwg2DuSYcNTsEY8QOPcSNLylt5NJZ7vwQFWyCKB7h6CW3LuYKJV7iTe7xSdl6AFkWJZWGWUZDtWwfaK2y8mH1Cu1hn9OxTaiim6PnXjyAa8oDVtsjHNIDe+9TJYeIEcwqA0flvbNDroXifoG0uNLWnIx1IoCtaabxDqHEA5JmYjEDgDD+IAtai1TitdAmpeSYTjohQitcS6AmBIiAg2g7Q3wLtA0Wj1no-0QfDdG+5bihzHhbABUBVYhDPuVZuToO59TZmHO+CQH63ynvhAsKFQDIOVKlVYhCcGgnwqI+0oDwGUnwlAtWJDYFkIQe+DyN9EgEPfqouBGsNG-Ciqg+OhcMHF3+KDKR2g8EEJoQqfGo1pRMJYc7OG7cECdy4bfe+Iwn4jCESMWRqFxErBvpXYJPIYR2nzlIqJWoYR5HkRCCBSiE76PUdTFGvwwo0F8qY9BNdLGlxsXYxuMVKlAA)) I seem successful in swapping the axes, and the rectangles seem to render fine. However the area chart (the actual violin) is completely absent. I'm completely at a loss on this. Any help would be much appriciated.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A violin plot example showing distributions for pengiun body mass.",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 600,
  "padding": 5,
  "config": {
    "axisBand": {"bandPosition": 1, "tickExtra": true, "tickOffset": 0}
  },
  "signals": [
    {"name": "plotWidth", "update": "(width - 30)/3"},
    {"name": "height", "update": "height * 1"},
    {"name": "trim", "value": true, "bind": {"input": "checkbox"}},
    {
      "name": "bandwidth",
      "value": 0,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 200, "step": 1}
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "penguins",
      "url": "data/penguins.json",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.Species != null && datum['Body Mass (g)'] != null"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "density",
      "source": "penguins",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "kde",
          "field": "Body Mass (g)",
          "groupby": ["Species"],
          "bandwidth": {"signal": "bandwidth"},
          "extent": {"signal": "trim ? null : [2000, 6500]"}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "stats",
      "source": "penguins",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["Species"],
          "fields": ["Body Mass (g)", "Body Mass (g)", "Body Mass (g)"],
          "ops": ["q1", "median", "q3"],
          "as": ["q1", "median", "q3"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "layout",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "penguins", "field": "Species"}
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "round": true,
      "domain": {"data": "penguins", "field": "Body Mass (g)"},
      "domainMin": 0,
      "zero": false,
      "nice": true
    },
    {
      "name": "hscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": [0, {"signal": "plotWidth"}],
      "domain": {"data": "density", "field": "density"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "penguins", "field": "Species"},
      "range": "category"
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "layout", "zindex": 1},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "yscale", "zindex": 1}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {"data": "density", "name": "violin", "groupby": "Species"}
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "xc": {"scale": "layout", "field": "Species", "band": 0.5},
          "width": {"signal": "plotWidth"},
          "height": {"signal": "height"}
        }
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "summary",
          "source": "stats",
          "transform": [
            {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.Species === parent.Species"}
          ]
        }
      ],
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "area",
          "from": {"data": "violin"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": {"parent": "Species"}}
            },
            "update": {
              "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "value"},
              "xc": {"signal": "plotWidth / 2"},
              "width": {"scale": "hscale", "field": "density"}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "rect",
          "from": {"data": "summary"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {"fill": {"value": "black"}, "width": {"value": 2}},
            "update": {
              "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "q1"},
              "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "q3"},
              "xc": {"signal": "plotWidth / 2"}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "rect",
          "from": {"data": "summary"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "fill": {"value": "black"},
              "height": {"value": 2},
              "width": {"value": 8}
            },
            "update": {
              "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "median"},
              "xc": {"signal": "plotWidth / 2"}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imL8E.png)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure this out, required an "orient" parameter in the encoding of the area mark.

"marks": [
{
"type": "area",
"from": {"data": "violin"},
"encode": {
"enter": {
"orient": {"value":"horizontal"},
"fill": {"scale": "color", "field": {"parent": "Species"}}
},
"update": {
"y": {"field":"value", "scale":"yscale"},
"xc": {"signal": "plotWidth / 2"},
"width": {"scale": "hscale", "field": "density"}
}
}
},

[Example Here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAExdgBsa47Tn1tM2uAA8kCU3G0QYbAO5Gy22TQiZlTBmoSENoAZmyKJnDitAzGTGyyAJ7ayBAQlNIgbrL0aAIADPky8DRkWGgAbIUyOEiyXtF5MlASIaVooEhW3gBCSOKyHSBM-bIACmwQdOpoAIwyalAA1gCiVr4oqL4McAs0ywDyISEQcJho+QC+lzJTZOJI+hBoANqgDwhwaCCm5gDqNByMEyDBwsiQmC+6AAFNl6NoALTaAoASgIAGYQDd3rYoRg4KVyjJQeDId8SmULAAqbSzLFSHGfb6+GgITLER47NDbXbDIyDVCgIw4ALfWBwZbxKxY7EgD54kYDOHAmQc-Rc1BFPkDIbC0XoRT9MhfGQIIwXU1dNAAJmqIB8cBwc2uAF0ZKTNm85bjvjgomQGEZnsTFPpvh6CH7ooHxOlRBJMhtY2FFGzUF7MIk-d82vpIYpMtYcAX0KSGAhKABlP1QGgKbQAQgAvNpxAx9PptAAyLueCHll4Ach6CWSAFkkGltNCyCjBy7Gy22x2sS7ZfLw1EppnMmIGIooHiowGg4nDcnwmmM1m8Ut5Jk2nB9AKQCOktoJ1OZyjMmRFGxQSYRJXhAasJTrZ43WGUZlSGO4HjDdBFVkWCbhAaxIXEc5BXtUoEOZZQEG0AB+Vt207VBtBeW1qm0CoCnyF0ZTXBlvSZdAfAhYN7QAg8j39GNuKTCAUyvUBM2zdAkDIP8+DJGQ-wAnAgJAsDawUEAoMfZ9nnTV9Rw-Sdgm-TI33HIzp1nUyDM-YyrKgtg8BAgBHOlTTgLx+kyZzMSgycXLckBPk8yQZB8zTLjXKDoEeDT00ZPF9CQRIAPOBYb2+ZDMnPY1vlg902GQc0cI9X0BNPGRtJfNSIJlViN3QRIYv0E0QAkxKjDgJACxkHK8QpIkQH-WIBR5Aqio0UBSvQY9BIfOtn2+MzDK-Ky0NkQqkCMMdiq1AAvOB-zQEJHlOGRxH2KExqGuBSEUU5jtOuB1x9dAYGa1r2u+QxxC6nqhqNKEXiKUB4MeX0zEwAEgVXcatsmuQIU2OQtzoYDKoWl95FjNG6oSsU2DMf6vvQcIGnBuHiqmpGyujCqQCq74ao0tC+rFCFyHCYDIpkLo4q9cI6ywzLzEwQrdygWLvuS1LMj2-lrGdVjBaibCQBakI0vtSWWu+Jqdda+WBkV1BZh5oLuqWXTr0kkBFNBB9-zTUATsPbDqcwZHse3dG2LxPRCfNBThuU4D0GZ55rhkKIWnvHDVcOoYrCgOCDellLRQxp9qprWqZCyzVKAENDYJwsHEJ+SHodyNCBvd3D7nBt6CUpGV1pp+K-e+CBy2QRRfb3Pju89zAhPPETL1ecSMvQXN80LKxi3DfsKwj7Qmw3kxutVqtc5ZqLLUUK2p7ameQG3lBKqdoZppAAOfvpdDxFjqFQATktQBV4WcLVDUMEFvaEhPZhjQrmRCoM07oBaETea2chi1EUKrJme9I5RxACSDmQww4u0xt8X+rUPp60IWhZOcE8JN0rv8QE8ICDaGtI-UuECpZvUIVnRapZUY7muFHaettEFQC1iEa+JUO72l7t1bm0dn4JFfk-eeOEwFDHwZlJKywGHUOBD-TkUJrRoIwWSHC2DtbMJAPrKWbCXyuUfokehZdIGmNYQzXB6BwokJTmXchFdfhQw0doWh9DuGyhJjdARjtxYiM9t3cR-dH4xxkUMd+QxFFaPVAqVRSxH51yUdom0JcNHZNSWgAAHHosEmDDGpxMWY3WFjvjBRoF5NxZDG5eKrr4-xbdIpdKAA)